# Make echo "autofill" a line of certain width

Tags: bash, echo

I have a rather large bash script which reads in a number of variables and then echoes them. I have no way to know beforehand the length of these variables and I do not want to shorten them or format them in any way - I just want them echoed in the same form they are read in.

To improve readability of my script's output I am echoing some lines to help the eye, something like this:

```
echo "--------------------------------"
echo "Here come some variables       |"
echo "                               |"
echo "a = $a and b = $b"
echo "                               |"
echo "End of the script              |"
echo "--------------------------------"
```

This will output:

```
--------------------------------
Here come some variables       |
                               |
a = 1.23e-19 and b = hello
                               |
End of the script              |
--------------------------------
```

What I want to achieve is for `echo` (or some alternative solution) to recognize how many empty spaces it needs to insert after the variables are printed so it can align a vertical line `|` with the rest of them, so that this output looks like this:

```
--------------------------------
Here come some variables       |
                               |
a = 1.23e-19 and b = hello     |
                               |
End of the script              |
--------------------------------
```

It does not need to be an `echo` only solution, but I would appreciate simplicity. Any ideas?

Comment: How about just omitting the trailing '|'?

Comment: If I wanted to just omit the | I would not have asked the question, since it's the solution I am using at the moment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So elaborating a bit on Axel's answer using `printf`can do this. If the line width is linewidth then:

```
a="1.23e-19" 
b="hello"
linewidth=30
echo "--------------------------------"
echo "Here come some variables       |"
echo "                               |"
printf "%-${linewidth}s |\n" "a = $a and b = $b"
echo "                               |"
echo "End of the script              |"
echo "--------------------------------"
```

does exactly what I want. Output:

```
--------------------------------
Here come some variables       |
                               |
a = 1.23e-19 and b = hello     |
                               |
End of the script              |
--------------------------------
```

Comment: You don't need `temp`. Just use `printf "%-${linewidth}s |\n" "a = $a and b = $b"`

Answer (score 2):

I don't have access to a linux machine now, but there also is `printf` that can be used on the command line. So you could use `printf " a = %10s and b= %10s |\n" "$a" $b"`.

You can play with the format specifiers to improve the result.

Comment: Thanks, but I do not want to change the variable's format.

Comment: @Miguel: I meant the width (10 characters in my example) and alignment (insert `-` after the percent sign for left alignment, otherwise right alignment is used).

Comment: You can use "%-5s" if you want that variable left-justified.