# Bash echo status

Tags: bash, echo

I'm trying to create a bash script which will display the statuses of multiple services.
The function I created to display the status is as follows:

```
printStatus() {
  if checkProcess "${1}"; then
    echo -e "${1} status: \t\t [RUNNING]"
  else
    echo -e "${1} status: \t\t [DOWN]"
  fi
}
```

The problem is that `$1` has a variable size, which for example, creates the following result:

```
Mysql status:        [RUNNING]
PHP-fpm status:          [RUNNING]
```

How can I manage to get the `[RUNNING]` tags perfectly underneath each other?
So I'd like to have it as follows:

```
Mysql status:            [RUNNING]
PHP-fpm status:          [RUNNING]
```

### EDIT - SOLVED

This is my function after [Mat's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23560005/1341719):

```
printStatus() {
  if checkProcess "${1}"; then
    printf "%-30s%s" "${1} status:"  "[RUNNING]"
  else
    printf "%-30s%s" "${1} status:" "[DOWN]"
  fi
  echo # <-- I know, being lazy here for the new line...
}
```

Comment: Regarding your solution, just set a variable `status=RUNNING` or `status=DOWN` as appropriate in the `if` statement, then follow it with `print "%-30s%s\n" "${1} status:" "$status"`.

Comment: It's a minified version of my actual function, it's doing more than just printing the status ;)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Make echo "autofill" a line of certain width](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22958873/make-echo-autofill-a-line-of-certain-width)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use printf instead of echo for this sort of thing. Something like:

```
printf "%-30s%s" "left justified text" "[status]"
```

If your process name is longer than whatever length you chose though, they'll miss-align (i.e. `printf` won't truncate).

Answer (score 1):

Use printf instead of echo. Example:

```
printf "%-16s%s" "${1}" "[RUNNING]"
```

You'll have to adjust the length of the formating to your max expected value.