# Create asterisk border around output in terminal?

Tags: bash, terminal

I need to create a border around the output of a command in terminal so that if, for example, the output of a command is this:

```
Apple
Paper Clip
Water
```

It will become this:

```
/==========\
|Apple     |
|Paper Clip|
|Water     |
\==========/
```

Thanks ahead of time for any and all responses.
-C.L

Comment: Is this your command, or are you trying to decorate the output of other commands? Please update your question to include the code you've already tried, and explain which part of it is giving you trouble.

Comment: I asked a similar question a while back, which might be relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22958873/make-echo-autofill-a-line-of-certain-width

Answer (score 1, accepted):

awk seems like the least insane way to go about this:

```
command | expand | awk 'length($0) > length(longest) { longest = $0 } { lines[NR] = $0 } END { gsub(/./, "=", longest); print "/=" longest "=\\"; n = length(longest); for(i = 1; i <= NR; ++i) { printf("| %s %*s\n", lines[i], n - length(lines[i]) + 1, "|"); } print "\\=" longest "=/" }'
```

`expand` replaces tabs that may be in the output with the appropriate number of spaces to keep the look of it the same (this is to make sure that every byte of output is rendered with the same width). The awk code works as follows:

```
length($0) > length(longest) {  # Remember the longest line
  longest = $0
}
{                               # also remember all lines in order
  lines[NR] = $0
}
END {                           # when you have everything:
  gsub(/./, "=", longest)       # build a line of = as long as the longest
                                # line
  print "/=" longest "=\\"      # use it to print the top bit

  n = length(longest)           # format the content with left and right
  for(i = 1; i <= NR; ++i) {    # delimiters; spacing through printf
    printf("| %s %*s\n", lines[i], n - length(lines[i]) + 1, "|")
  }

  print "\\=" longest "=/"      # print bottom bit.
}
```

The **most** insane way to do it, and I dare you to dispute this, is with sed:

```
#!/bin/sed -f

# assemble lines in the hold buffer, preceded by the left delimiter
s/^/| /
1h
1!H
$!d

# make a copy of it in the pattern space
x
h

# isolate the longest line (or rather: a line of = as long as the longest
# line)
s/[^\n]/=/g
:a
/^\(=*\)\n\1/ {
  s//\1/
  ba
}
//! {
  s/\n=*//
  ta
}

# build top bit, print it
s,.*,/&\\,
p

# build measuring stick
s,.\(.*\).,=\1,

# for all lines in the output:
:lineloop

# fetch the line
G
s/^\(=*\n\)\([^\n]*\).*/\1\2/

# replace it with = to get a second measuring stick
s/[^\n]/=/g

# fetch another copy of the line
G
s/^\(=*\n=*\n\)\([^\n]*\).*/\1\2/

# inner loop:
:spaceloop

# while the line measuring stick is not as long as the overall measuring
# stick
/^\(=*\)\n\1/! {
  # append a = to it and a space to the line for output
  s/\n/\n=/
  s/$/ /
  b spaceloop
}

# once that is done, append the second delimiter
s/$/|/
# remove one measuring stick
s/=*\n//
# put the second behind the actual line
s/\(.*\)\n\(.*\)/\2\n\1/
# print the line
P
# remove it. Only the measuring stick remains and can be reused for the
# next line
s/.*\n//

# do this while there are more lines to be processed
x
/\n/ {
 s/[^\n]*\n//
 x
 b lineloop
}

# then build the bottom bit and print it.
x
s/=/\\/
s/$/\//
```

Put that in a file `foo.sed`, use `command | expand | sed -f foo.sed`. But only do it once to confirm that it works. You don't want to run something like that in production.

Comment: The two ways you mentioned are great, the only problem I am having at this point is that, for example lets use the command fortune with either of these methods. It will return a text box that looks like this: [example](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0By-WW2LVuci6bHE1VHdteTYwbjg/view?usp=sharing) Which is a bit off because of spacing or something I am unsure, it only happens sometimes, but I need something that would work perfectly all the time. Can you tell whats going wrong with it in the picture provided

Comment: Some fortunes contain tab characters that are rendered oddly (they are a single character but rendered like many). To fix that, pipe through expand first: `fortune | expand | awk allthatstuff`

Comment: Thank you, I would not have been able to figure this out without your help and if I had, it would be a lot more messy than what you provided. I really do sincerely mean this. Again, thank you for all the time you spent towards my, what seems to be, overly complicated problem.

Comment: Aw, the awk bit isn't terribly complicated, and the sed bit isn't really serious (I did it because doing things with sed that shouldn't be done with sed is a great source of brain teasers). Oh, by the way, you can put the awk code above in a file of its own as well and use `awk -f foo.awk`. It's getting to the length where doing that instead of putting the whole code inline is probably a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

Not in the language you were looking for, but succinct and readable:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
input = STDIN.read.split("\n")
width = input.map(&:size).max + 2
bar = '='*(width-2)
puts '/' + bar  + '\\'
input.each {|i| puts "|"+i+" "*(width-i.size-2)+"|" }
puts '\\'+ bar + '/'
```

You can save it in a file, `chmod +x` it, and pipe your input into it.

If you "need" to have it in a one-liner:

```
echo e"Apple\nPaper Clip\nWater" | 
ruby -e 'i=STDIN.read.split("\n");w=i.map(&:size).max+2;b="="*(w-2);i.map! {|j| "|"+j+" "*(w-j.size-2)+"|" };i.unshift "/"+b+"\\"; i<<"\\"+b+"/";puts i'
```